# FullCalendar list-views, height: auto not working as expected

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm using the demo [list-views.html](https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-3.2.0/demos/list-views.html) and trying to set `height: auto`, but this does not work! The Calendar has a vertical scrollbar.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    height: 'auto',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'listDay,listWeek,month'
        },

        // customize the button names,
        // otherwise they'd all just say "list"
        views: {
            listDay: { buttonText: 'list day' },
            listWeek: { buttonText: 'list week' }
        },

        defaultView: 'listWeek',
        defaultDate: '2017-02-12',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: '2017-02-01'
            },
            ***continue-demo
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will help but did you include the print.css? That may correct it. Also on the print css be sure to set media="" to media="print".